# Exclude User-Agent from Apache logs

Tags: apache, ubuntu, logging, referer

I'm looking for a solution that you can have :)
I try to exclude **user-agent** to apache log, but keep **referer**.
Here is what I tried

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\"" common
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/xxx_access.log common
```

But when I do that, `Referer` is excluded too ...

I tried to replace `common`by `combined` but still the same ...

And here is what I want to do:

```
 IP - [date] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 9062 "Referer"
```

Any ideas?
It's not possible ... ?

`combined` display both, Referer and User Agent
Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into your `/etc/apache2/apache.conf` (or `apache2.conf`).
At the bottom you should see

```
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
```

So try to replace

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

by

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\"" combined
```

Restart Apache, and it should works.

Comment: Ok thank you. It works. But I have another question. Is it possible to hide Referer if he contains "google.com". Juste hide Referer, not the log ??